# Fracture Transform throws boolean given

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I am using a Transformer in my Laravel project. When I don't include an other object in the Transformer there isn't any problem but when I include the `Customer` object I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Transformers\CustomerTransformer::transform() must be an instance of App\Models\Customer, boolean given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/project/vendor/league/fractal/src/Scope.php on line 365 and defined

When I printed the object from `Scope.php` there weren't any booleans in it. What could be the problem? (The code crashes after Review `#298`.

[image]

How I call the code:

```
$reviews = $this->review->paginate();
$transformer = new ReviewTransformer();
$with = $request->get('with', null);
if($with) {
    $with = explode(';', $with);
    $transformer->parseIncludes($with);
}
return $this->response->paginator($reviews, $transformer);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed the problem, I'm an idiot..

I had the following include in my Transformer class:

```
public function includeCustomer(Review $review) 
{
    $customer = $review->customer;
    return $this->collection($customer, new CustomerTransformer);
}
```

The problem is that `$customer` is an Item an not a Collection. I had to change `this->collection` to `this->item`.

Comment: I did same mistake too :-)

Comment: me too :) 
change the return line